# Can I have a global Exception handler in my Xamarin Android app without app crash?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My situation is as follows:
I maintain code of an existing app
Some events cause a crash for a good reason (for example, there is no internet connection) and the user presses a button that does something which requires internet connection.
I want to handle them globally.
And.....
**I do not want an android crash.**, just a message that something went wrong.

I already know AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser . I can handle an exception and for instance call a toast message. However, the app crashes anyway. I don't want that. If it does not work, the user should get a toast message and be able to press another button.

Is there a way to prevent an Android crash in this situation (a way that works globally)?

Comment: did you try an `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` ? just think about what you asked here for a moment.... if the app crashes, you want the user to not have a crash and be able to continue using it, by displaying a toast instead of crashing... consider a scenario of a null-pointer instead of using the internet connection when there is none. how do you expect that to work and behave?